# REGEX: How to count the permutations of a word or words in a given string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, algorithm, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to use regex to count the permutations of a word or words in a given string? Let's take "NEOTWONE" as our examples which should return a count of "4"

```
  NEO --> 'ONE' --> +1
  OTW --> 'TWO' --> +1
  TWO --> 'TWO' --> +1
  ONE --> 'ONE' --> +1
```

This is what I have so far and I couldn't get the regex to work properly.

```
const nums = ['ZERO','ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR','FIVE','SIX','SEVEN','EIGHT','NINE'];

function amount(str,count=0) {
  for (const n of nums) {
    RegExp(`\\b[${str}]+\\b`,'g').test(n) && count++;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(amount('ONE')); // 1
console.log(amount('ONEOTW')); // 2
console.log(amount('ONENO')); // 1
console.log(amount('NEOTWONE')); // 2
```

As you can see, the 2nd, 3rd & 4th example above did not render the correct outcome which should be:

```
console.log(amount('ONEOTW')); // 3
console.log(amount('ONENO')); // 2
console.log(amount('NEOTWONE')); // 4
```

I'm new to regex, any feedback will be greatly appreciated. Million thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:**

Inspired by Trincot, this is a "non-generator" version of the solution:

```
function permutations(arr) {
  return arr.length === 1
    ? arr
    : arr.flatMap((v,i,a) => permutations([...a.slice(0,i),...a.slice(i+1)]).map((d) => `${v}${d}`));
}

function createRegex(arr) {
  const p = arr.flatMap((v) => permutations([...v]));
  return `(?=${p.join('|')})`;
}

const nums = ['ZERO','ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR','FIVE','SIX','SEVEN','EIGHT','NINE'];
const regex = createRegex(nums);
const amount = (str) => str.match(RegExp(regex,'g'))?.length || 0;

console.log(amount('TEN')); // 0
console.log(amount('ONE')); // 1
console.log(amount('ONEOTW')); // 3
console.log(amount('ONENO')); // 2
console.log(amount('NEOTWONE')); // 4
console.log(amount('NEOTWONEINEIGHTOWSVEEN')); // 8
```

Comment: Note that your `permutations` function does not need `res`; you never pass it in the recursive call, so `(d) => res.concat(v,d)` can simply be replaced by `(d) => v + d`.  And if you were generating arrays instead, you could use `(d) => [v, ...d]` or `(d) => [v].concat(d)`.

Comment: @Scott, you're absolutely right. Simply concatenating `v + d` would suffice. Another a-ha moment for me, thank Scott :)

Comment: An interesting corner case about your requirements.  If your target words included both `TEN` and `NET`, would you expect the count for `ETNE` to be two, since `ETN` matches and `TNE` matches, or to be four, since `ETN` matches both `TEN` and `NET`, as does `TNE`?

Comment: Logically speaking, 2 might be the way to go for each test case.

Comment: Though it might be ok to concatenate `v+d` in the function "permutations" for this example to output the correct result. However, as a standalone function or even in this example, it's safer to concatenate `${v}${d}` as template literal. The output results will always be a string as expected, whereas, `v+d` will output the sum. Another gotcha moment for me while testing.

Comment: I'm not sure one is more logical than the other, but if that's your requirement, then a regex solution like trincot's makes sense... although with many keywords, or with longer ones, the regex will grow quickly.

Comment: I usually do permutations as array -> array and do any necessary concatenation afterward.  I find that more generic.  But yes, this solution was for an array of Strings concatenated back into strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a *huge* regular expression for that:

First, create all the unique permutations of all input strings (`nums`).

Concatenate these into one regular expression, using `|` as separator, but use look-ahead, so that one character can be part of a match multiple times. So for instance, for "ONE", the regular expression would be:

```
(?=ONE|OEN|ENO|EON|NEO|NOE)
```

But then you would also include all permutations of "ZERO" and all the other words.

```js
function* permutations(word) {
    if (word.length <= 1) return yield word;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        for (let perm of permutations(word.slice(0, i) + word.slice(i + 1))) {
            yield word[i] + perm;
        }
    }
}

function createRegex(words) {
    const allPermutations = words.flatMap(word => [...new Set(permutations(word))]);
    return RegExp("(?=" + allPermutations.join("|") + ")", "g");
}

function countMatches(regex, phrase) {
    return phrase.match(regex)?.length ?? 0;
}

const nums = ['ZERO','ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR','FIVE','SIX','SEVEN','EIGHT','NINE'];
const regex = createRegex(nums);
for (const test of ['ONE', 'ONEOTW', 'ONENO', 'NEOTWONE']) {
    console.log(test, countMatches(regex, test));
}
```

Note that for the second test the answer is 3, not 2, since "NEO" also counts.

Comment: What a mind blowing reply & solution this is, Trincot! This is actually the first time I've ever witness generator being use to solve an algorithm. What a learning experience this is. The way you use Single Responsibility Principal, generator, and optional chaining is just so clean and impeccable. Thank you so much for sparing your time to answer my question :)  PS: For those who might need Trincot's solution in the future, swap out the "for of loop" at the end with the following: `const amount = (str) => countMatches(regex,str);`

Comment: Very interesting to see a technique that grows with both the number of terms and their individual factorials!  I have no idea how to express this in big-O notation.